# 3 fixed Columns (header and footer) using DIVs, NO Absolute DIVs, IE friendly, ALL columns stretch equally

Tags: css, html, semantic-markup, xhtml-transitional

Left to right, Col1 id 560px wide with 10 px padding, middle column, 250px wide with 5px padding and Col3 (siderbar) is 200px wide with 3px padding. Background coloR, no matter text length in any column should stretch vertically equal. No javascript (jQuery workarounds) to make it work. It needs to be pure Semantic Markup with CSS. Each Column should have a nested column of color were content will go. Column 1 should be SEO prominant which means the highest nested column for Google and other Search Engines to crawl. I have used 'The Holy Grail" layout, articles at "A List Apart" and these solution are so convoluted that they push the main columns left and than the nested columns push them with padding back right. This is crazy! I try to adjust these examples, but they're not editable by just adjusting a width in the CSS or the padding, etc. Can you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

The known solutions are complex because, unfortunately, what you are describing is just not easily accomplished in pre-HTML5/CSS3. It's not crazy, it's the state of the art. The people who developed and describe the solution in A List Apart are the authoritative industry experts on figuring this stuff out.

The best options we have are either to use JavaScript to compute column size and lay it out at runtime, or be satisfied with the manual tweaking required by a pure CSS solution. For most sites, I recommend using JS, since good column layout can be considered an "enhancement" - the semantic markup laid out vertically is still readable, and SEO-optimized, and JS-enabled clients can [progressively enhance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement) that markup to have a pretty, 3-column presentation.

If your site is public-facing and has a typical demographic distribution, you're looking at ~90% with JS enabled, and the remaining 10% are accustomed to sites not being very pretty or looking quite right.

Comment: I appreciate your quick feedback. Here is a link: http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/ultimate-3-column-blog-style-pixels.htm. I like this solution and I can add a style and extra div to fix this liquid style/width to make it fixed.

Comment: I tried to adjust the left, Col1 to 560px wide with a working content area of 540px (making margin to 0 10 0 10). Col2 (or center pink column) to 250px wide with a working content area of 230px (making margin to 0 10 0 10). Finally the sidebar, Col3 (the yellow column) to 200px wide with a working content area of 190px (making margin to 0 5 0 5).

Comment: I broke it down, made changes, followed the given comments, but I believe they're wrong. The HTML starts with a #colmask DIV -> #colmid DIV -> #colleft DIV and than a #col1wrap DIV that holds .col1 followed by a relative .col2 and .col3. Can you help adjust this to 560px, 250px, 200px nested with 540px, 230px, 190px. I keep breaking it. Thank you. Phillip

Comment: @Phillip so you want 540 with a 10 gutter, 250 with a 10 gutter, and 190 with a 5 gutter? You realize this adds up to 1010, which is just a bit too wide for the typical 1024 target resolution? Typically want to avoid going over 960 for that.

Comment: Actually, the first Column is a div of 560px with a nested content div at 540. The next ones are correct. There is also a header div which is 1000px wide with a placeholder height of 200px and a footer div which is 1000px with a placeholder height of 300px. I think you had it, but you read the "540", missed the "560". Was the link helpful. It's what I want from appearance and it's compliant with ALL browsers (even IE), but I can't seem to adjust the websites dimensions because it's created with a very "funky" method with "margins" pushing "divs" around? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hello my fellow developers and programmers. So, I posed a question, gave a link with the right look and a unique, but not the ONLY solution to my question above. I read about 'faux columns' or tiled backgrounds repeating on a y-axis, jQuery additions, but there must be a clean, ALL browser compliant (IE7+) solution with DIVs, CSS at a fixed width. If it has to be liquid, ok, but the nested DIVs inside each column should be easily accessible to add, edit and modify content without breaking the page. I'm open to suggestions after reading and testing adobe/devnet, alistapart, and many more. TY-p